# Event delegation, use of event Target in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is the html code:

```
<table id="bagua-table">
<tr>
  <th colspan="3"><em>Bagua</em> Chart: Direction, Element, Color, Meaning</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nw"><strong>Northwest</strong>
    <br>Metal
    <br>Silver
    <br>Elders
  </td>
  <td class="n"><strong>North</strong>
    <br>Water
    <br>Blue
    <br>Change
  </td>
  <td class="ne"><strong>Northeast</strong>
    <br>Earth
    <br>Yellow
    <br>Direction
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="w"><strong>West</strong>
    <br>Metal
    <br>Gold
    <br>Youth
  </td>
  <td class="c"><strong>Center</strong>
    <br>All
    <br>Purple
    <br>Harmony
  </td>
  <td class="e"><strong>East</strong>
    <br>Wood
    <br>Blue
    <br>Future
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="sw"><strong>Southwest</strong>
    <br>Earth
    <br>Brown
    <br>Tranquility
  </td>
  <td class="s"><strong>South</strong>
    <br>Fire
    <br>Orange
    <br>Fame
  </td>
  <td class="se"><strong>Southeast</strong>
    <br>Wood
    <br>Green
    <br>Romance
  </td>
</tr>
```

The script is to make any selected cell highlight and if clicked again, remove the highlight, What's the use of the `selectedTd` variable and the line that contains `target.parentnode`, what do those two lines do?

This is the Javascript code:

```
let table = document.getElementById('bagua-table');

let selectedTd;

table.onclick = function(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  while (target != this) {
    if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
      highlight(target);
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}

function highlight(node) {
  if (selectedTd) {
    selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  selectedTd = node;
  selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target.parentNode` will get the parent node that the current node belongs to. The line is setting the `target` to be the HTML element which holds the current element.

E.g. `<div class="parent"><button class="child" /></div>`. If `target` was the `button`, then the parent node would be the `div`.

This is happening every loop until a `td` element is found, or it reaches the global object.

`selectedTd` is used to keep a state of what the currently selected cell is. 
Every time the `highlight` function is called, it'll check if there is a `selectedTd` that already exists. The existing one will have its `highlight` class removed and will be replaced by the `node` passed into the function. This `node` will have the `highlight` class added.